# Jquery UI Datepicker don't change language until change month or year

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm using jqueryui datepicker as below code:

```
 $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['fr']);
        $('#datepicker').datepicker({
            changeMonth:true,
            changeYear:true,
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
            beforeShowDay:function (date) {
                if (!checkAvailableDate(date))
                    return [false, "", "Unavailable"];
                return [true, ""];
            },
            onSelect: dateClick

        });
```

Everything work ok, but language. I want it display with fr language, but the first time it showed in english, until I change month or year, it display in fr. How can I fix this?

Thanks so much

Comment: Can you post a http://jsfiddle.net showing this ?

Comment: @andrew : I think jsfiddle.net doesnot support `jqueryui`

Comment: just include it in the html `<script type="text/javascript" src="lnk/to/jqryui"></script>`

Comment: Is working fine here http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/8svCb/; can you provide your head HTML markup? Are you running your code in DOMREADY?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try enclosing your script for datepicker in `document.ready()`

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['fr']);
        $('#datepicker').datepicker({
            changeMonth:true,
            changeYear:true,
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
            beforeShowDay:function (date) {
                if (!checkAvailableDate(date))
                    return [false, "", "Unavailable"];
                return [true, ""];
            },
            onSelect: dateClick

        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting default language inside the code in:
http://dev.krownoutaouais.ca/includes/js/jquery/i18n/jquery.ui.datepicker-fr.js

So you can remove the language set, and the extend too, on jQuery UI datepicker instance:

```
 $('#datepicker').datepicker({
     changeMonth: true,
     changeYear: true,
     dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
     beforeShowDay: function (date) {
         if (!checkAvailableDate(date)) return [false, "", "Unavailable"];
         return [true, ""];
     },
     onSelect: dateClick
 });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/8svCb/